# How Do I Enable Select Items In Menus Of InsydeH2O Setup Utility On Acer Aspire V5?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

I use the F2 key at system boot to enter InsydeH2O on my Acer Aspire V5
I use the Left and Right arrows to change menu
When I try to use the Up and Down arrows to select menu items there is no joy.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hit Enter on your keyboard after you highlight the field you want to change. Then you can use arrow up and down to make changes.